# How to pass (props or state ) to main layout React component from child

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

i am new to react...

- app.js

  - Main layout

    - Child 1
    - Child 2
    - etc...

The main layout has a h1, h2, style.object, so i need to modify this depending on child component.

What is the best way to change the h1, h2 etc... of this Main layout ?

```js
class App extends Component {

  render()  {
    
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <Navbar />
            <Main>
                { this.props.children }
            </Main>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
    

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="Main">
                <div className="Header" style={this.props.styles.header}>
                    <h1 style={ this.props.styles.h1 }>{ this.props.header1 }</h1>
                    <h2 style={ this.props.styles.h2 }>{ this.props.header2 }</h2>
                </div>

                <div className="MainContent">
                    <div className="InnerContent">
                        { this.props.children }
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: what u need exactly

Comment: If I understand your use-case correctly, this is similar to passing a handler/callback from a parent component into the child components. Normally, you'd pass a callback function from the parent component into the child component (as a prop), and then your child component can call that function with the correct arguments at the correct moment in the lifecycle, e.g. componentDidMount. The callback will then set the correct state for the parent component.

Comment: I have my main layout which is the same for all app, inside this main layout i have h1, h2... so i need to change those value (h1, h2...) from the child component

Comment: In addition to my suggestion above - regarding passing a callback to the child element - you can also start looking into re-organizing your components. Is there a way the the parent component can determine those values on its own before passing other props to its children? Finally, if you find that you have to make a lot of these data connections across components, it might be time to start looking into Redux.

Comment: @Nicks: ok ..`this.props.styles` will be `this.state.styles` then you define method  (`changeMainStyles`)inside Main that accepts new styles and call `setState` .. this method should be propagated via `context` then children will call this method `this.context.changeMainStyles(newStyle)`

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI, Thanks for help but for what i read they say "Context" is not stable so it might be better not using it...

Comment: @ArashMotamedi, i am using redux for my async data like list of thing from my API, but for small data like title i am not sure if this is worth it ? How would be the best way to implement it ?

Comment: @Nicks : it is so stable ... see my answer

Comment: @Nicks If you have Redux wired up, then you can totally manage all your data relationships within Redux as long as your reducers are composed correctly. But also, it totally makes sense that for a relatively straightforward situation like this, just passing a callback into your child component will suffice, just like how you'd pass a click handler, etc. into a child element. Or use Abdennour's solution, though for this case, I'd stay away from context and work with props and state. Context is suitable when the parent and child that need to collaborate are separated by intermediate components.

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.styles` will be `this.state.styles`

then

you define method (`updateHeader`)inside `Main` that accepts new styles and call `setState` ..

this method should be propagated via `context`

then

children will call this method via `this.context.updateHeader(newStyle,..)`

## Main :

```
class Main extends React.Component {

    static childContextTypes = {
      updateHeader: React.PropTypes.func
    };  


    updateHeader(styles, header1, header2) {
      this.setState({styles, header1, header2})
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="Main">
                <div className="Header" style={this.state.styles.header}>
                    <h1 style={ this.state.styles.h1 }>{ this.state.header1 }</h1>
                    <h2 style={ this.state.styles.h2 }>{ this.state.header2 }</h2>
                </div>

                <div className="MainContent">
                    <div className="InnerContent">
                        { this.props.children }
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Support `Something` is one of the `Main` children :

```
class Something extends React.Component {
     static contextTypes = {
          updateHeader: React.PropTypes.func
        };  ;

       componentDidMount() {

         this.context.updateHeader({styles:header:{} , h1:{}, h2{} }, "i am header1", "i am header 2");
       }

}
```